# General question on Sever Side Google Tag Manager

Tags: tags, google-tag-manager, server-side

So I've been looking into page speed and have been reading about Google's Server Side GTM. Wondering if a lot of people have transitioned to this and what the costs could be for a high traffic marketing site. If the site already has a ton of tags, is this something that can be set up by the marketing department or developers, or is it more likely needed to hire someone who specializes in GTM.

If anyone has experienced this transition and has any information to share regarding page speed results that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The page speed change will vary depending on your site and the health of your container. You can measure it. Just go to your site, go to devtools, block GTM, reload the page. Compare that to how fast it loads with it.

General conclusion: Most GTM containers have zero influence on page load speed. Even if the library is not cached. Before it's non-blocking.

Keep in mind that best practice for implementing server-side GTM is using it in conjunction with the regular GTM. Which kinda defeats the purpose since sending GA hits is not something affecting your site speed. Unless you create real hardware load with them. Which is pretty difficult.

Now, to maintain your sGTM, you do need to increase spendings, but the main expense is usually not on maintaining the instance with the container. The main expense has a more long-term nature. The maintenance of the backend instance will require more expensive experts, much tougher debugging, typically involvement of normally more expensive backend devs and so on.

Generally, going sGTM route just because it sounds like fun is a bad idea to do in production. There should be a good business case to justify it.